# Button click method not running through - leaves text that should be cleared at the start

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I'm creating a search function, where you can use two search boxes (not used at the same time - two separate search buttons) to bring up results in a gridview. If the search doesn't produce anything, it comes up with text saying so. But when you enter a new successful search, often the no results text will still be there, even though its cleared at the start of the method. And sometimes it takes a couple of clicks to get it to even appear.

```
Protected Sub Button1_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click    
  Dim tCodeText As String

  Label1.Text = "" 

  'This is where it should clear the text

  If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text) Then
    'Do nothing  
  Else
    tCodeText = TextBox1.text

    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [tCodes] WHERE [TCode] LIKE '%" + tCodeText + "%'"

    GridView1.Visible = "True"
  End If

  If Gridview1.Rows.Count = 0 Then
    Label1.Text = "No results meet your search criteria"
  End If
End Sub

Protected Sub Button2_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

  Dim descText As String
  Dim splitArray() As String
  Dim sqlText As String

  Label1.Text = "" 

  'This is where it should clear the text

  If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox2.Text) Then
    'Do nothing
  Else
    DescText = TextBox2.text

    splitArray = Split(descText)

    sqlText = "SELECT * FROM [tCodes] WHERE [Description] LIKE '%" + splitArray(0) + "%'"

    For index = 0 To splitArray.Length - 1
      sqlText += "OR [Description] LIKE '%"
      sqlText += splitArray(index)
      sqlText += "%' "
    Next

    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = sqlText

    GridView1.Visible = "True"
  End If

  If Gridview1.Rows.Count = 0 Then
    Label1.Text = "No results meet your search criteria"
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem might be due to when Databinding occurs for your GridView.

Databinding does not happen until late in the page life cycle so you will need to force Databinding of your GridView earlier, before you can query the number of rows.

After you assign your `SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand` try Databinding by adding the following line:

```
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Alternately you could move your check of number of rows to the GridView's DataBound event. This might actually be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks very much John, that seems to have fixed the problem. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this statement right after the Textbox.Text = ""

> Application.DoEvents()

This can sometimes be required when many visible elements are updated in rapid succession in one (or multiple) forms.

Se: [MSDN here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx) for details on the DoEvents method (It's quite useful sometimes in VB and .NET).

Comment: `Application.DoEvents()` is only relevant to WinForms applications, not ASP.NET.

Comment: @John, You are of course correct. Ooops I didn't observe the tags for the question before I answered, got it from search on VB. I'll leave my answer for now as it might be useful for someone else getting here by the VB.NET or .NET tags.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input!